# adding CocoaLibSpotify

Tags: ios, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm having trouble adding `CocoaLibSpotify` to my IOS XCode project...

1. Dowloaded cocoalibspotify-master
2. Ran CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library successfully (sample projects also run successfully)... trying to generate the libCocoaLibSpotify.a file?
3. Added CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library-Prefix, CocoaLibSpotify iOS Library, and SPLoginResources
4. Also followed instructions to add frameworks from here: https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify

Right now my build simply fails, I've tried a few other things (importing more of the files etc) and still it fails. All of the header files in are in red, so they obviously aren't being included somehow.

Can someone give step by step instructions on this process?

Comment: Can you indicate how it fails? Its good that you've outlined what you've tried but knowing as much as possible about what goes wrong should be useful.

Comment: Did you also add the other linker flags `-all_load` and `-ObjC`?

Comment: yes, I've added -all_load and -ObjC

Comment: it may have something to do with framework search paths or header search paths? where should these point?

Comment: since you got it working it would be helpful to post an answer and accept it, mine isn't working. :)